# How can i get html headers with phpunit using Selenium2?

Tags: selenium, http-headers, phpunit

```
public function testheaders()
{
         $url=$this->url('http://www.example.com/index.php');
         $kur = get_headers($url);
         var_dump($kur);
}
```

I got the `error` : `get_headers(): Filename cannot be empty`.

My class extends `PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase` like my all my other tests.

Answer (score 0):

[get_headers()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) is a PHP function that will give you the headers return by an HTTP request to a specified url. The parameter you need to give is a string, but $this->url() return an PHPUnit_Selenium-object.

If you want the headers of that known URL, why not do directly?

```
$kur = get_headers('http://www.example.com/index.php');
```